# Sub-class of Number persistently gets converted back to built-in Number Object/Function

Tags: javascript, class, javascript-objects, prototype, prototype-programming

In an effort not to pollute or extend the prototype `Number` object, I am attempting to create a class that extends `Number`. However, when I do this and then try to add anything to it or even add it to itself, it is converted back to a number.

I understand this is occurring because it is taking the numeric `valueOf` property value and returning that value added to another number, but I would like for the value to always retain its subclass without having to create additional methods like:

- `.add(x)`
- `.sub(x)`
- `.mul(x)`
- `.div(x)`

Is there a way to achieve this, similar to how both the `Number` and `BigInt` types allow for these types of computations? I could—but would prefer not to—extend the built-in Number object to support my custom methods, but anytime I try working with them now, they lose all their methods.

For example:

```js
let num = 5;
console.log(num.constructor); // Number
num += 2;
console.log(num); // 7
console.log(num.constructor); // still Number
```

However, working with my extended class:

```js
class MyNum extends Number {
    constructor (num = 0) {
        super(num);
    }
    get isEven() { return this.isInt && this % 2 === 0 }
    get isOdd() { return this.isInt && this % 2 !== 0 }
}
let num = new MyNum(5);
console.log(num.constructor); // MyNum
num += 2;
console.log(num); // 7
console.log(num.constructor); // back to Number
```

Furthermore, if the only solution here is to add methods like `.add(x)`, would I need to recreate a new class instance whenever a computation like `.add(x)` is done, or is there another more native way to add to the existing object's value.

If the below is the only workaround, I may stick to extending the built-in `Number` object:

```js
class MyNum extends Number {
    constructor (num = 0) {
        super(num);
    }
    add(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() + x) }
    sub(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() - x) }
    mul(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() * x) }
    div(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() / x) }
    mod(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() % x) }
    get isEven() { return this.isInt && this % 2 === 0 }
    get isOdd() { return this.isInt && this % 2 !== 0 }
}
```

Comment: Unlike your title says, it does not get converted back to `Number`. Applying a `+=` operator gives a *primitive* value. The `num.constructor` expression temporarily wraps the primitive `num` into a `Number`.

Comment: @trincot I see what you mean. `num instanceof Number` returns false. I may add a `math()` method which accepts a parameter for the current value, computes the value, and then returns the new value as a new `MyNum` instance.

Comment: *"similar to how both the `Number` and `BigInt` types allow for these"*: they don't. `(Number(1) + Number(2)) instanceof Number` is false. Also there, the result is a "number" primitive (or "bigint" primitive respectively).

Comment: @trincot it makes sense to me that these numbers are actually number "primitives" but then why/how do these number primitives inherit methods from `Number.prototype`? If I define `Number.prototype.round` for example, it is available for use with number primitives.

Comment: That is because primitives are wrapped into native objects when you try to access a property. This is behaviour you cannot override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want

```
num += 2;
```

to result in `num` being a `MyNum` before, and a `MyNum` after, I'm afraid it isn't possible. As [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-applystringornumericbinaryoperator) says, all values will be converted to primitives (`valueOf`, `toString`), after which the primitives are either concatenated together or added together - and the concatenation or addition of primitives will result in plain primitives as the result, either a string, number, or BigInt.

Adding new explicit methods like `.add` is the only real option.

The value of a number object is [in an internal slot](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-object) which isn't changeable (not that you'd want to anyway, since mutation could be confusing). I don't think there's a better approach than `add(x) { return new MyNum(this.valueOf() + x) }` etc. But you can slightly clean up your methods by removing the `valueOf` calls, there's no need for them.

```
add(x) { return new MyNum(this + x) }
sub(x) { return new MyNum(this - x) }
```

Comment: I plan to give this a few more days or so before selecting an answer just to see what other workaround people might come back with. Thank you for your detailed response!

Comment: It makes sense to me that these numbers are actually number "primitives" as trincot mentioned in a comment on my original question, but then why/how do these number primitives inherit methods from `Number.prototype`? If I define `Number.prototype.round` for example, it is available for use with number primitives.